# How can I make an array when there are duplicate values?

Tags: php

I have data that contains links for a navigation bar. It should be structured exactly like an unordered list, with a header and then all of the corresponding links below that header. I cannot seem to build this correctly. This would be some sample data from the database.

```
HEADING     LIST         LINK
Favs        google          http://...
Favs        yahoo           http://...
Favs        stackoverflow   http://...
Site        first link      http://...
Site        second link     http://...
```

This data should then **group** all of the headings into one and then display the links associated with them. Is this even possible or maybe there is a better way?

I plan to use the "HEADING" and "LIST" to dynamically build a `<UL>` type of menu.

---

Well, this isn't working as I had hoped. Here is the array that is being built from the database. Notice how sidebar[0] and sidebar[1] rpeat the value "Favs". This will repeat the same value on my form which I don't want. All of the duplicate names should be grouped together. Is this possible?

```
Array
(
    [date] => Sun, 25 Oct 2009
    [sidebar] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Favs] => Array
                        (
                            [author_sidebar_link] => google.com
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Favs] => Array
                        (
                            [author_sidebar_link] => yahoo.com
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [Offsite] => Array
                        (
                            [author_sidebar_link_title] => something
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [Something] => Array
                        (
                            [author_sidebar_link] => something else
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
<?php
$menu = array(
     'Favs' => array(
         array('LIST' => 'google', 'LINK' => 'http://...'),
         array('LIST' => 'yahoo', 'LINK' => 'http://...'),
         array('LIST' => 'stackoverflow', 'LINK' => 'http://...')
     ),
     'Site' => array(
         array('LIST' => 'first link', 'LINK' => 'http://...'),
         array('LIST' => 'second link', 'LINK' => 'http://...')
     )
);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Asaph, thank you. What I was hoping to do was to make these dynamic in that I would not have to hardcode into an array, the LIST and LINKS. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
$menu = array('Favs' => array(
                              'Google' => 'http://',
                              'Yahoo' => 'http://'
                        ),
              'Site' => array(
                              'First' => 'http://',
                              'Second' => 'http://'
                        )
             );
foreach($menu as $category => $items){
    echo '<h3>' . $category . '</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($items as $name => $url){
        echo '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Hi JoostK, are you stll here? This isn't working as expected.

Comment: Yes I'm still alive, don't worry :) Just tested in TextMate, works fine. In response of your edit, how do you build that structure? Could you provide that piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
<?php
$_list = array();
foreach($_data as $k => $v){
 $_list[$v['HEADING']][$v['LIST']] = $v['LINK'];
}

foreach($_list as $k => $v){
 echo "<ul>".$k;
 foreach($v as $kk => $vv){
  echo "<li><a href='".$vv."'>".$kk."</a></li>";
 }
 echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```